# Change the file path names of HTML elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, src

I have a HTML page .In my head section i have below code

```
    <link href="/Content/css/Stylesheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/Content/css/jquery.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery.datepick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How do I change the file path names of the above HTML elements to the
below one using jquery dynamically

```
<link href="http://localhost:9090/Content/css/Stylesheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost:9090/Content/css/jquery.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://localhost:9090/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:9090/Scripts/jquery/jquery.datepick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:9090/Scripts/jquery/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the path of it through Javascript ? You can use relative path instead.

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq He asks for a chair  , you answer for a banana. what if he wants to send this html file to someone in other domain ???

Comment: @RoyiNamir its because he might need a banana instead of a chair. We need to first understand the root problem.

Comment: yes i am trying to take a HTML page  using cross domain concept

Comment: @SunilGeorge I guess you do need a chair. ( as you asked for).

Comment: Now we are on same page as it was not mentioned on the question calarification was necessary

Comment: @RoyiNamir Shaikh is not answering. He is commenting to prepare a potential answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("link[href^='/Content/css']").attr('href', function(i, oldhref) {
    return 'http://localhost:9090' + oldhref;
});
$("script[src^='/Scripts']").attr('src', function(i, oldsrc) {
    return 'http://localhost:9090' + oldsrc;
});
```

Comment: This should do the work for you. Here is the documentation link for the answer provided by @Barmar. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Starts with Selector is the perfect option.

Comment: i tried the code got an error in console"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: link[href^=/Content/css]"

Comment: It needed some extra quoting because of the `/` characters. Try it now.